# Android ProgressDialog not working together with AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-dialog, android-progressbar, android-runonuithread

I'm trying to run a function on another thread. Unfortunately it just keeps on going without dismissing. The Try catch works if i don't have it within the run function. I Thought it could be the AsyncTask that i have inside the function.

i also catch this error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

Here is my code

```
    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    InputStream is = null;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(AvvikelseActivity.this, "Registrerar", "Vänta");

        //Start the function here


        //start a new thread to process job
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //heavy job here
                //send message to main thread
                try {

                    Bitmap immage = null;
                    //preapare the image
                    immage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgurl);
                    final int maxSize = 960;
                    int outWidth;
                    int outHeight;
                    int inWidth = immage.getWidth();
                    int inHeight = immage.getHeight();
                    if (inWidth > inHeight) {
                        outWidth = maxSize;
                        outHeight = (inHeight * maxSize) / inWidth;
                    } else {
                        outHeight = maxSize;
                        outWidth = (inWidth * maxSize) / inHeight;
                    }
                    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(immage, outWidth, outHeight, false);


                    //initiate string imagedata, which will be the string for the actual image
                    String imagedata = null;
                    //encode the image
                    imagedata = encodeTobase64(immage);

                    //Setting nameValuePairs
                    final List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);

                    //adding the string variables
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("reporter", reporter));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("department", department));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("errortype", errortype));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("title", title));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("percaution", percaution));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("imgurl", imgurl));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dataset", dataset));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", imagedata));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phoneid", android_id));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("typ", TAG_TYP));

                    //Task to upload the information in background, on another thread
                    new AsyncTask<ApiConnector, Long, Boolean>() {
                        @Override
                        protected Boolean doInBackground(ApiConnector... apiConnectors) {
                            return apiConnectors[0].uploadImageToserver(nameValuePairs);
                        }
                    }.execute(new ApiConnector());

                    //tell the user that it is registred
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), getString(R.string.registred), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    //change window to main
                    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(mainIntent);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("MainActivity", e.toString());
                }

            }
        }).start();


    } //Here ends onClick(View v)
});
```

Comment: Hi, can you show me "encodeTobase64" please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to have a different thread. `AsyncTask` already works on different thread. Also you need to dismiss your dialog and start the new activity when your `AsyncTask` is finished.

Try this

```
btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    InputStream is = null;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(AvvikelseActivity.this, "Registrerar", "Vänta");
        try {
                Bitmap immage = null;
                //preapare the image
                immage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgurl);
                final int maxSize = 960;
                int outWidth;
                int outHeight;
                int inWidth = immage.getWidth();
                int inHeight = immage.getHeight();
                if (inWidth > inHeight) {
                    outWidth = maxSize;
                    outHeight = (inHeight * maxSize) / inWidth;
                } else {
                    outHeight = maxSize;
                    outWidth = (inWidth * maxSize) / inHeight;
                }
                Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(immage, outWidth, outHeight, false);
                //initiate string imagedata, which will be the string for the actual image
                String imagedata = null;
                //encode the image
                imagedata = encodeTobase64(immage);
                //Setting nameValuePairs
                final List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                //adding the string variables
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("reporter", reporter));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("department", department));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("errortype", errortype));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("title", title));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("percaution", percaution));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("imgurl", imgurl));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dataset", dataset));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", imagedata));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phoneid", android_id));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("typ", TAG_TYP));
                //Task to upload the information in background, on another thread
                new AsyncTask<ApiConnector, Long, Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Boolean doInBackground(ApiConnector... apiConnectors) {
                        return apiConnectors[0].uploadImageToserver(nameValuePairs);
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                        //tell the user that it is registred
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), getString(R.string.registred), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        //change window to main
                        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(mainIntent);
                    }
                }.execute(new ApiConnector());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", e.toString());
            }
        }
    } //Here ends onClick(View v)
});
```

But if you want to use a new thread then just add this to your `AsyncTask` and remove the code inside this method from outside.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    //tell the user that it is registred
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), getString(R.string.registred), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    pDialog.dismiss();
    //change window to main
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(mainIntent);
}
```

Comment: @Rihit5k2 For some reason   Override on onPostExecute turns red. Any clues?

Comment: Method does not override method from its superclass

Comment: My mistake. Just change the parameter type of `onPostExecute` to `boolean`

Comment: protected void onPostExecute(boolean result)  like this? It does still not work? Should OnPostExecute have Override at all? @Rohit5k2

Comment: Yes just change the parameter. it would work with our without override. I personally choose to keep it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87985/discussion-between-edvard-akerberg-and-rohit5k2).

Comment: It is boolean but it still not working. What do you mean by changing the parameter?

Comment: Oh yes its my typo. Its "Boolean" not "boolean"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this

```
           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
```

Instead of plain `pDialog.dismiss();`

Any update to the Ui has to be made from the Ui thread or the main thread.